# Switch port maximum output power

Tags: network-interface, poe

I have a switch who have not the power over ethernet capability.

I want to power very small devices with the power available on the utp cable.

Do you know the max value (HP 24 ports switch) ?

Thanks

Comment: You're not really supposed to do that, and I don't think there's a DC bias on it normally anyway. I would be suprised if you could get more than miliamps out, and certainly not enough to drive a return ethernet signal.

Comment: It is called power over Ethernet (PoE), and when your switch supports it, it can deliver maybe op to some 40W per port. Voltages and currents vary per specific standard. Wikipedia has a nice article on it, http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet Most important question here is how you think you will be implementing it.

Comment: I know ;-) I want to know if it's possible to power very small devices on ethernet with non POE switch. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mind voiding your HP warranty by modifying internally or do you want to farm power from the signal or maybe add DC externally via an adapter.  Depending on your model you might be able to modify it easily to add POE to some ports. Generally it is 48V 10W min per port but in your case you don't need that so you either customize or pay for off the shelf $$.

I designed a 16 chan. POE rack for AVAYA (nee Lucent) over 10 yrs ago by 3rd party contract so I have some familiarity.

You only need a few diodes to insert and extract DC if you have centre tapped transformers already in the HP switch. It must be a floating DC power supply.

Here is a basic interface example showing extraction from both lines. You only need one bridge per port and possible only 1 diode if you already know the polarity and aren't using crossover cables.

[image]

Comment: I suppose it's possible to add the bridge externally and transform a non poe port into poe port. Exact ? Thanks !

Comment: It seems that POE injector exists to adapt a non POE port into POE enabled port. Great ! http://beyond-wifi.com/poe/